# WiX CopyFile with unknown path on DiskCost

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.10

I need to copy external file, which location I acquire from dialog. File should be copied on installation, so I'm trying to use `CopyFile` element. Problem is, that `SourceProperty` for `CopyFile` is not set when installer starts, so it throws `Error 1606. Could not access network location  .` after `CostFinalize`. I assume, that installer is trying to acquire size of external file. Is there any way to force installer to not compute size of `CopyFile` element, or I must implement custom action for copying of file, so Installer would not know about it?

My file component:

```
<Component Id="ConfigurationIniFileDeploy" Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Guid="MY-GUID">
    <CopyFile Id="ConfigurationIniFileCopy" SourceProperty="WIXUI_INI_LOCATION" DestinationProperty="APPLICATIONFOLDER"/>
</Component>
```

Property filled in dialog before installation:

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_INI_LOCATION" Value=" " />
```

Documentation specifies for `SourceProperty`:

```
The property does not have to exist in the installer database at creation time; it could be created at installation time by a custom action, on the command line, etc
```

Shouldn't be installer ignoring it by default?

My version of toolset: **WiX v3.10.3 (Stable)**

Comment: I've just come across the same issue. Anyone with ideas, please?

Comment: I ended up using custom action for copying of file, if I remember correctly.